# Irrational number "test"?

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers

Suppose we have a finite quantity $a$, which we would like to prove to be irrational, supposing that it is indeed irrational.

Then, would it be enough to show that $$a=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{u_n}{v_n},$$ for some positive integers $u_n,v_n$, where $u_n,v_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. If so, then would there have to be some divisor properties between the denominator and numerator so that cancellation does not produce an integer or rational number as $n\to\infty$, e.g. suppose $(u_n,v_n)=1$ for all $n$ ?

Comment: As the rational numbers $\mathbb Q$ are [dense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set) in the real numbers $\mathbb R$, any real number (either rational or irrational) is the limit of a sequence of rational numbers. So, no, the answer is no (any $a$ can be written in that form for suitable integers $u_n$ and $v_n$)

Comment: The condition that $v_n \nmid u_n$ is extremely ineffective, it only rules out $a$ being an integer.  Don't you mean that the gcd of $v_n$ and $u_n$ should be 1?

Comment: @Erick yes you're right. I've updated the question.

Comment: All rational numbers have finite continued-fraction representations.  So if you can prove a number has an infinite continued fraction representation it must also be irrational.

Comment: Given a number, it is undecidable in general whether it is real or not (because there are more real numbers than there are Turing machines).

Comment: @user1729: Surely you meant it's undecidable in general whether a number is *rational* or not, not whether it's real or not. Otherwise I'd wonder what you could have in mind by the phrase "given a number".

Comment: @KCd Yeah, sorry, I think I was going for "irrational".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a similar condition that is sufficient: there exists a sequence of integers $u_n, v_n \to\infty$ such that $(u_n, v_n) = 1$ and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} v_n a - u_n = 0.$$
(Alternatively, we could just require that $a$ not be exactly equal to any $u_n/v_n$ rather than $(u_n,v_n)=1$.)

Comment: Thanks Erick. Do you have a reference for this or a resource for further details? I'd like to study more.

Comment: I'd be shocked if the idea isn't in any book on irrationality, but I don't know a reference offhand (maybe try something basic like Niven's "Numbers: Rational and Irrational"?).  The proof is very simple: if $a=p/q$, and $a \ne u_n/v_n$, then $v_n a - u_n$ is a non-zero rational with denominator (at most) $q$.  Therefore it is at least $1/q$ in absolute value, and can't go to $0$.

Comment: @ Erick but isn't this just the same as my original question, since $$\lim_{n\to\infty}v_n a-u_n=0 \iff \lim_{n\to\infty}a=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{u_n}{v_n}\iff a=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{u_n}{v_n},$$ and $u_n,v_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$, $(u_n,v_n)=1$ ?

Comment: @pbs Absolutely not.  Compare your first iff against $a=1$, $u_n = n$, $v_n = n+1$.  The $\Leftarrow$ is very much false.

Comment: @ Erick wow - I see that now: while $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{u_n}{v_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}=1,$$ we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+1)\times 1-n=\lim_{n\to\infty} 1 = 1\neq 0.$$

Comment: @ Erick thank you very much for your answer. I had an inkling my thoughts might be "on the right track", but clearly "hadn't got it quite right" !

Answer (score 3):

Consider

$$u_n = \frac{10^n - 1}{3} \hspace{1cm}v_n = 10^{n}$$

Then:

$$\frac{u_n}{v_n} = 0.\underbrace{3333\cdots 3}_{n \text{ times}}$$

What means that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{u_n}{v_n} = 0.333\cdots = \frac{1}{3}$$

So no, that condition is not sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

This will not suffice. Let $a$ be an irrational number then there
is some sequence of rational numbers $(q_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ that
converges to $a$. Denote $q_{n}=\frac{u_{n}'}{v_{n}'}$ where $u_{n}',v_{n}'$
are coprime. Let $u_{n}=nu_{n}',v_{n}=nv_{n}'$ then 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{u_{n}}{v_{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{nu_{n}'}{nv_{n}'}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{u_{n}'}{v_{n}'}=\lim_{n\to\infty}q_{n}=a
$$

So every irrational number satisfy your property.

But similarly if $a$ is rational take $q_{n}\equiv\frac{na}{n\cdot1}$
which will show that every rational number also satisfy this test.
So in fact all real numbers satisfy the test and so we can't get information
about a number that satisfies this test - they all do